# Official definition of tawarruk تورك(in the context of salat, not in context of islamic finance "tawarruq"تورق)

Tags: salat

1) What is the official definition of tawarruk تورك in the context of salat?

2) As far as I know, language can evolve over time. As time goes by, people often create new words/terminologies for certain things to ease the explaining of things. I want to know when was the earliest known written usage of the word tawarruk? (historically speaking, I'm talking about the  history of terminology usage)

3) Where did this term originally came from (country and distric)?

4) What written source / who is the person that is most reliable, credible, & authoritative to define this term "according" to you?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by your questions 2, 3 4 tawarruk was practiced at the time if the prophet pbuh as it was mentioned in ahadith. Please consider adding some information to explain by editing your post (edit-link at the bottom).

Comment: Yes it was practiced back then, but did they really used the term tawarruk back then at that period? As far as I know, language evolves with time, as time goes by people often create new words/terms for certain things to ease explaining things. I want to know when was the earliest known written usage of the word tawarruk? By knowing when, hopefully we can know from where did it came from..?